# Not able to add SPF record to my domain in Cpanel

Tags: ajax, cpanel, spf

I am trying to add SPF records to my domain in Cpanel, but no luck, I am getting Ajax error! Its not happening in either of the cases; adding new SPF records or edit the existing one. How to add this? I have searched many links to fetch an answer for my problem, but not finding any.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello @Web I'm experiencing that right now.
Did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

In Email section go to Email Authentication, and Enable the SPF.
See this https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9214/31/cpanel-email-authentication-tool-spf-and-dkim-records

Answer (score 0):

I use Hostgator and experienced the same issue and despite all my efforts (tried all possible browsers, edited another TXT record, etc), I could not get past the Ajax error while setting the SPF entry. I finally gave in and contacted hostgator support and asked them to configure the entry from their side and it worked perfectly. So if you do get stuck here... worse case scenario - contact support